# Pushing back string to vector of objects

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I was browsing some code I wrote for a school project, that at a closer inspection looked weird to me. I had a class similar to the one below:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::string s) : _s(s) {}
private:
    std::string _s;
};

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hiyo";

    std::vector<Foo> f;
    f.push_back(str); // Compiles. Weird to me though.
    f.push_back(Foo(str)); // Predictably, this compiles as well.

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the first call to `push_back` a valid statement, even though `str` is not a `Foo`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Class `Foo` has a non-explicit ctor taking one argument of type `std::string` (i.e. [Converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)), which means it could be implicitly casted from a `std::string`.

```
f.push_back(str);      // implicit casting from std::string to Foo
f.push_back(Foo(str)); // explicit casting from std::string to Foo
```

Note if you make the ctor `explicit`, the implicit casting will be prohibited.

```
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(std::string s) : _s(s) {}
//  ~~~~~~~~
private:
    std::string _s;
};
```

and then

```
f.push_back(str);      // invalid now
f.push_back(Foo(str)); // still valid
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it talks about `explicit`

Answer (score 7):

The first push back will automatically initialize a `Foo` object given a `string` object; through your initializer list.

(Expects a `Foo` object, gets a string: can a `Foo` object be initialized with a single string? Yes, its initializer list has single element and the object is initialized from that element).

For details, see e.g.:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: The initializer list shouldn't be significant. Will still compile without it.

Comment: What if `Foo(std::string s)` is `explicit`?

Answer (score 2):

I think that in the first pushback it is automaticaly initializes `Foo(str)`
So its basicaly tha same!